# CakePHP 1.2 - Cache::delete doesn't work in prod

Tags: php, caching, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have a curious problem. I have a shell file runned by cron each 15 minutes to gathers different RSS data. I use cache helper in CakePHP to save the result as this :

```
echo 'Update cache...';
Cache::delete('AggregatedNews.getHome');
Cache::delete('AggregatedNews.getHome.fr');
Cache::delete('AggregatedNews.getHome.en');

Cache::write('AggregatedNews.getHome',$this->AggregatedNews->getHome());
Cache::write('AggregatedNews.getHome.fr',$this->AggregatedNews->getHome(array('AggregatedNews.language'=>'fr')));                          Cache::write('AggregatedNews.getHome.en',$this->AggregatedNews->getHome(array('AggregatedNews.language'=>'en')));

echo 'Cache updated!';
```

This code works well on my computer and in dev environment on the server. But in prod, nothing happens. If I manually delete the cache file to see if Cache::Write works, it's still the same.... Somebody have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error messages?  What version of PHP are you running on dev server versus prod?

Comment: I've got no error message. For PHP. the remote is 5.3.5 on a Linux box and local is 5.3.6 on OS X.

Comment: Nothing in your server's error log?  Unfortunately I haven't dealt with CakePHP 1.2 so I'm not sure what would be causing this.  Are you sure you have the proper caching engine on your prod machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable reason is you forgot to set write permission to tmp folder.

Comment: This is a very, very highly likely reason.

Comment: I redo a chmod -R 777 and now it seems to work if I call the cake console directly...I'll wait to see if the cron works well....if yes, I'll bang my head in the wall! By the way, is there a way to "force" CakePHP writes cache with full right? (I'm a really beginner, you notice?)

Comment: Confirmed....that was the problem. I feel kind of stupid right know! Anyway, thanks guys ;)